# Problem plotting decision boundary with simple neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to train a very simple neural network with a single perceptron using a 2D input vector (x1, x2).

I've implemented what I think is the correct back propagation below. Using the returned weight vector, I get a line that is nowhere near the decision boundary of the data.

```
    def train_nn(self, training_set, labels):

        for _ in range(self.epochs):
            preds = np.dot(self.weights.T, training_set.T)
            z = sigmoid(preds)
            error = z - labels
            #back propogation - find derivative with respect to weights
            derror_dy = error
            dy_dz = sigmoid_deriv(preds)
            derr_dz = derror_dy * dy_dz
            derr_dweights = np.dot(training_set.T, derr_dz.T)
            dz_dweights = self.lr * derr_dweights
            self.weights -= dz_dweights        
        return self.weights
```

[image]

I am getting the correct classification when I run the prediction using the weights though.

[image]

Is the improper boundary because of the use of the sigmoid function? Or is there an error in my back propagation calculation? Appreciate any help!